# twilio.rest missing from twilio python module version 2.0.8?

Tags: twilio

The Twilio python quickstart guide says to use a submodule called twilio.rest .

But after installing the twilio module today via `sudo pip install twilio`, which installed version 2.0.8, there appears to be no module (or object) called "rest" within the twilio module.

Where is twilio.rest?

Comment: By the way, here is the twilio module's github, which also says to use twilio.rest https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python

Comment: Aha! That fixed it. Thanks! Yes, ten minutes before doing the pip install, I had used port to install 2.0.8 (the latest version with a Portfile), but I then uninstalled it, and figured that once uninstalled it wouldn't affect pip. Textbook example of spooky action at a distance, haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you should check.

First, if you already have a package installed with `pip`, running `pip install package-name` will NOT upgrade the package. To upgrade the package to the newest version, run

```
pip install --upgrade twilio
```

Second, we often see this error occur because people named the file containing their Twilio code `twilio.py`. This means that trying to `import twilio.rest` will fail because Python is looking in the `twilio.py` file for the `.rest` module. To resolve the problem use a different filename.

If you have more problems with the `twilio` module and `ImportError` messages, there is a full set of documentation here: http://readthedocs.org/docs/twilio-python/en/latest/faq.html#importerror-messages

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptom but my problem was I named my view handler twilio.py. That caused a conflict with twilio library. Just name your py file something else like phone.py.