# All packages erased after instlaling Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I upgraded my local and remote versions of python to 2.7.9 - somewhere along the way - all of my packages were removed? I cannot make use of Flask outside of a virtualenv? While I was installing remotely I downloaded a virtualenv and proceeded to install pip, flask, etc.

I am not certain that downloading Python 2.7.9 is to blame. Whenever I enter the python interpreter and import my previously installed packages, i.e. Flask, they are not available.. I then proceed to sudo install globally and still the packages are not available despite my terminal saying the installations were success -  for some reason my packages will now only work inside of a `virtualenv`?

I have follow this post [Import error in twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887927/import-error-in-twilio)
and I have identified Python 2.7 directory and contents as follows

`/usr/local/bin/python`

```
> 2to3        ipcontroller   iptest    pydoc      python2.7-config idle
> ipcontroller2  iptest2   python     python2-config ipcluster  
> ipengine       ipython   python2    python-config ipcluster2 
> ipengine2      ipython2  python2.7  smtpd.py
```

`/usr/bin/pip`

only one pip installed

..again even when I install outside of a virtualenv, I receive a successful install message for i.e. Flask but it is not installed when I check in the python interpreter, how could I fix this? Is this unique to Python 2.7.9?

Comment: probably because you were using `/usr/bin/python` before and you installed a second interpreter not upgraded the system python

Comment: I did upgrade python, I compared past interpreter instances with my current - at the beginning of an interpreter instance, the python version is displayed

Comment: regardless, how could I fix?

Comment: what does `which -a python` output

Comment: because you see a newer python version does not mean you updated the system python, the fact you have a `/usr/local/bin/python` assures me you did not

Comment: which -a python
`/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python` How could I fix this?

Comment: yes so you have two installs, try starting interpreters with  `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python` try importing in both.

Comment: Can not import in either directory path

Comment: what does import sys sys.path show? And when you install a package with pip where does in say it is installed?

Comment: `The program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`

Comment: you have to run that from a python interpreter not bash, what did you see when you ran `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: `/usr/bin$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 24 2014, 21:39:12) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys sys.path
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import sys sys.path
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: it should be on different lines, where is pip installing your packages?

Comment: `/usr/bin$ pip install Flask
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: ok so start an interpreter with `/usr/local/bin/python` on one line import sys then on another line sys.path and see if `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` is in there

Comment: `/usr/local/bin$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 24 2014, 21:39:12) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named path
>>> ` Will not let me import `sys.path`

Comment: I did not have `import sys.path` in my comment, just `sys.path` after importing sys

Comment: `['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

Comment: so it is there, so in that same interpreter `import flask` does not work?

Comment: `>>> import flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask
>>> ` No

Comment: ok one last thing, do import sys, `sys.path.insert(1,"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")` then try to import again, on separate lines again

Comment: that works session only, for a global effect, I have tried utilizing https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables but my `echo $PATH` displays `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and still importing flask or any library does not seem to be reading my $PATH ?

Comment: if I were you I would remove the `/usr/local/bin/python` then reinstall pip using `sudo python get-pip.py` you can get that file here  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py