# ImportError: No module named twilio

Tags: python, macos, twilio, osx-yosemite

I believe this has something to do with having multiple versions of python but after fiddling for many hours I am just plain lost.  I am on OSX Yosemite.  I have tried installing and reinstalling the twilio libraries multiple times.
The script won't run past line 1 without throwing this error.

> ImportError: No module named twilio

```
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
```

Basic info for Twilio and python

```
twilio==4.5.0

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Find which directory `twilio` installed into - you don't say how you installed it, which python you installed it with and which python you are trying to run it from.  Then check the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: As an aside, you might consider using `pyenv` to manage your Python versions; it's designed to solve problems like this. https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and found the solution here: [Import error in twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935768/5847662)

It could be that you simply already have a file named twilio.py that is being imported instead of the library, [twilio-python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install).  Remove your twilio.py and twilio.pyc and hopefully it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Python 2.7` try installing `twilio` with `pip2` (the python 2.7 pip version)

```
sudo pip2 install twilio
```

And remember to always keep you main `pip` version the same as your `python` version

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, the problem was emanating from naming conflict. Had named my project file "twilio.py" thus

> from twilio.rest import Client 
>   gave an error