# Cannot import twilio into python

Tags: python, syntax-error, twilio

I am attempting to import twilio into python 2.7.13 shell for a project. I did so through cmd prompt and in the shell itself. This is the result in both cases:

```
import twilio

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import twilio
ImportError: No module named twilio
```

I have uninstalled and have reinstalled python and have done the same for twilio through pip with no issues in the process. (Twilio is sitting in my site-packages folder.) Clearly python is unable to find twilio, thus indicating a pathing problem. I attempted to make an environmental variable to path the two but to no avail.

I have scoured forums on here and other sites but cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887927/import-error-in-twilio

Comment: What is the name of the Python file where you put your code? Is it by any chance also called Twilio?

Comment: what does cmd say when you type `python --version`

Comment: @MarcosPlacona - L:\twilio-twilio-python-2f0f62d\twilio is how the raw install put it in. No projects have been saved under the name twilio.

Comment: @Joe- Python 2.7.13.

Comment: @Mr_U4913- Running through the solutions on the forum you linked now, no luck so far however.

Comment: Ah I figured out the issue thanks to that forum. It seems that I had installed python 3.5 on my computer. Once I uninstalled 3.5 and downloaded twilio again through pip I was able to import it with no errors. Thanks for your help everyone!