# ImportError: No module named twilio.rest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, twilio

I realize this question has been posted before (1, 2), but none of the posted solutions have worked for me.

- I've correctly installed twilio in python 2.7.0 using pip install
- I've checked to make sure none of the projects are named twilio.py
- I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, confirmed twilio version 5.7.0
- tried relaunching IDLE

I'm still getting the "ImportError: No module named twilio.rest" message. What can I do?

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8978993/5986816

Comment: it says it's already up to date :(

Comment: Do any of the answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5687052/28376) help? Particularly to do with the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your pip command that you are running is from the right path, just as described in their [FAQ](http://twilio-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)

This one worked for me:

> /usr/local/bin/pip install twilio

Comment: thanks for the link - but the FAQ is for when you're unable to find twilio.rest or rest, but my error message is just for 'twilio' module. also, is the /usr/local/bin/pip install twilio for unix/linux? I don't use either